When the search box is emptied, all the data appears on my pagination
I'm encountering an issue with my search box. When I clear it, all the data in my pagination appears. My objective is for it to return only the five data entries displayed on the currently active page when cleared.


document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", searchTable);

function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, j, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var displayRow = false;
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j]) {
        txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          displayRow = true;
          break; // Break the inner loop if match found in any column
        }
      }
    }
    if (displayRow) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
      displayPagination();
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  const tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
  const dataRows = Array.from(tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")).slice(1); // Exclude header row
  const headerRow = table.querySelector(".header");
  const itemsPerPage = 5;
  let currentPage = 1;

  function displayRows(page) {
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
    dataRows.forEach((row, index) => {
      if (index >= startIndex && index < endIndex) {
        row.style.display = "";
      } else {
        row.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }

  function displayPagination() {
    const pageCount = Math.ceil(dataRows.length / itemsPerPage);
    const paginationDiv = document.querySelector(".pagination");
    paginationDiv.innerHTML = "";

    // Previous button
    const prevButton = document.createElement("button");
    prevButton.textContent = "Prev";
    prevButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (currentPage > 1) {
        currentPage--;
        displayRows(currentPage);
        updatePaginationButtons();
      }
    });
    paginationDiv.appendChild(prevButton);

    // Page buttons
    for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
      const button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = i;
      if (i === currentPage) {
        button.classList.add("active");
      }
      button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        currentPage = i;
        displayRows(currentPage);
        updatePaginationButtons();
      });
      paginationDiv.appendChild(button);
    }

    // Next button
    const nextButton = document.createElement("button");
    nextButton.textContent = "Next";
    nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (currentPage < pageCount) {
        currentPage++;
        displayRows(currentPage);
        updatePaginationButtons();
      }
    });
    paginationDiv.appendChild(nextButton);
  }

  function updatePaginationButtons() {
    const paginationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".pagination button");
    paginationButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
      if (index === currentPage) {
        button.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        button.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  }

  // Initially display header row
  headerRow.style.display = "";

  displayRows(currentPage);
  displayPagination();
});
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" />
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>#</th>
    <th style="width: 60%">Name</th>
    <th style="width: 40%">Country</th>
    <th style="width: 40%">Age</th>
    <th style="width: 40%">Email</th>
    <th style="width: 40%">Surname</th>
    <th style="width: 40%">Middlename</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>germanchapperd@gmail.com</td>
    <td>Alfie</td>
    <td>Papa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>chupapi@gmail.com</td>
    <td>shy</td>
    <td>Mama</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>islanda@gmail.com</td>
    <td>xerxe</td>
    <td>cici</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>funnymantio@gmail.com</td>
    <td>naknak</td>
    <td>fiif</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>natagpun@gmail.com</td>
    <td>neknek</td>
    <td>pekpek</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>ricobuenva@gmail.com</td>
    <td>hikhik</td>
    <td>hokhok</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>labis@gmail.com</td>
    <td>tektek</td>
    <td>kita</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>ohhhhhh@gmail.com</td>
    <td>tektek</td>
    <td>leklek</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>funnymantio@gmail.com</td>
    <td>naknak</td>
    <td>fiif</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>natagpun@gmail.com</td>
    <td>neknek</td>
    <td>pekpek</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>ricobuenva@gmail.com</td>
    <td>hikhik</td>
    <td>hokhok</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>labis@gmail.com</td>
    <td>tektek</td>
    <td>kita</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>ohhhhhh@gmail.com</td>
    <td>tektek</td>
    <td>leklek</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>funnymantio@gmail.com</td>
    <td>naknak</td>
    <td>fiif</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>natagpun@gmail.com</td>
    <td>neknek</td>
    <td>pekpek</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>ricobuenva@gmail.com</td>
    <td>hikhik</td>
    <td>hokhok</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>labis@gmail.com</td>
    <td>tektek</td>
    <td>kita</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>ohhhhhh@gmail.com</td>
    <td>tektek</td>
    <td>leklek</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>funnymantio@gmail.com</td>
    <td>naknak</td>
    <td>fiif</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>natagpun@gmail.com</td>
    <td>neknek</td>
    <td>pekpek</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>ricobuenva@gmail.com</td>
    <td>hikhik</td>
    <td>hokhok</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>labis@gmail.com</td>
    <td>tektek</td>
    <td>kita</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>ohhhhhh@gmail.com</td>
    <td>tektek</td>
    <td>leklek</td>
  </tr>
</table>



I attempted to resolve the issue by placing the displayPagination() function within the Sort function, but it's still not functioning properly. Additionally, when I try to search again, all the data appears in my table.

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this problem is in any way related to CSS?

Hey Nico, my apologies for the confusion. It seems I tagged this incorrectly. The issue solely lies within JavaScript, and I'm still struggling to find a solution.

Feel free to edit your question and clarify it

Can you add the HTML alongside the JavaScript as a snippet or some images of the project for a clear vision?

Sure @AbdurRehman I've added the HTML now

I am working on your code. I have one thing to ask. When a user searches for a name, there are multiple duplicates (exact 4) of the same name, but the search function results show one of them. I wanted to ask if this was done intentionally or a bug.

Running your snippet gives me "message": "Script error.", Please fix it.

To make the table only display the rows that are on the 1st pagination page when the search box is cleared, There are some adjustments that need to be done in the searchTable function. like resetting all rows to hidden before searching, handling the empty search separately, and displayRow reset for each row to filter according to the search.
Additionally, There are a lot of bad practices in the code you have provided from using var to the structure & formatting of the code. I have made some changes and added the maximum best practices in this updated version of the JS code you provided which hopefully also meets your requirements and fixes the issue you were facing.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    const tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
    const dataRows = Array.from(tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")).slice(1); // Not Include header row
    const headerRow = table.querySelector(".header");
    const itemsPerPage = 5;
    let currentPage = 1;

    // Function to display rows according to the current page
    function displayRows(page) {
        const startIndex = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage;
        const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
        dataRows.forEach((row, index) => {
            if (index >= startIndex && index < endIndex) {
                row.style.display = "";
            } else {
                row.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    }

    // Function to display pagination
    function displayPagination() {
        const pageCount = Math.ceil(dataRows.length / itemsPerPage);
        const paginationDiv = document.querySelector(".pagination");
        paginationDiv.innerHTML = "";

        // Previous button
        const prevButton = document.createElement("button");
        prevButton.textContent = "Prev";
        prevButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (currentPage > 1) {
                currentPage--;
                displayRows(currentPage);
                updatePaginationButtons();
            }
        });
        paginationDiv.appendChild(prevButton);

        // Page buttons
        for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
            const button = document.createElement("button");
            button.textContent = i;
            if (i === currentPage) {
                button.classList.add("active");
            }
            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                currentPage = i;
                displayRows(currentPage);
                updatePaginationButtons();
            });
            paginationDiv.appendChild(button);
        }

        // Next button
        const nextButton = document.createElement("button");
        nextButton.textContent = "Next";
        nextButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (currentPage < pageCount) {
                currentPage++;
                displayRows(currentPage);
                updatePaginationButtons();
            }
        });
        paginationDiv.appendChild(nextButton);
    }

    // Function to update pagination buttons
    function updatePaginationButtons() {
        const paginationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".pagination button");
        paginationButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
            if (index === currentPage) {
                button.classList.add("active");
            } else {
                button.classList.remove("active");
            }
        });
    }

    // Function to search the table
    function searchTable() {
        const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        let displayRow = false;

        // Reset all rows to be hidden
        dataRows.forEach(row => row.style.display = "none");

        // If input is empty, reset to the current page
        if (filter === '') {
            displayRows(currentPage);
            return;
        }

        // Search through the rows
        dataRows.forEach((row, index) => {
            const td = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (let j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                const txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    displayRow = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (displayRow) {
                row.style.display = "";
                displayRow = false; // Reset for the next row
            }
        });

        // Update pagination to reflect the search results
        displayPagination();
    }

    // Event listener for the search input
    document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", searchTable);

    // Initially display header row and pagination
    headerRow.style.display = "";
    displayRows(currentPage);
    displayPagination();
});


The main problem is your displayRows function is affecting the visible and hidden rows from searchTable function.
I slightly modified your code and added the pagination div since it's not included in the snippet you provided.
Here is the working code based on your requirement:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let currentPage = 1;
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    const itemsPerPage = 5;

    document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", () => searchTable(true));

    function searchTable(fromInput) {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, j, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
            var displayRow = false;
            let txtValue = tr[i].innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                displayRow = true;
            }
            if (displayRow) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        if (fromInput) currentPage = 1;
        displayPagination();
    }

    function displayPagination() {
        const filteredRows = document.getElementById("myTable").querySelectorAll("tr:not([style*='display: none']):not(.header)");
        const pageCount = Math.ceil((filteredRows.length) / itemsPerPage);

        showStart = (currentPage -1) * itemsPerPage;
        filteredRows.forEach(function(tr, index) {

            if (index < showStart || index >= showStart + itemsPerPage) {
                tr.style.display = "none";
            }
        });

        const paginationDiv = document.querySelector(".pagination");
        paginationDiv.innerHTML = "";

        // Previous button
        const prevButton = document.createElement("button");
        prevButton.textContent = "Prev";
        prevButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            currentPage--;
            searchTable(false);
            updatePaginationButtons();
        }
        });
        paginationDiv.appendChild(prevButton);

        // Page buttons
        for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = i;
        if (i === currentPage) {
            button.classList.add("active");
        }
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            currentPage = i;
            searchTable(false);
            updatePaginationButtons();
        });
        paginationDiv.appendChild(button);
        }

        // Next button
        const nextButton = document.createElement("button");
        nextButton.textContent = "Next";
        nextButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (currentPage < pageCount) {
            currentPage++;
            searchTable(false);
            updatePaginationButtons();
        }
        });
        paginationDiv.appendChild(nextButton);
    }
        
    function updatePaginationButtons() {
        const paginationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".pagination button");
        paginationButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
        if (index === currentPage) {
            button.classList.add("active");
        } else {
            button.classList.remove("active");
        }
        });
    }

    searchTable(false);
});
    <input
      type="text"
      id="myInput"
      placeholder="Search for names.."
      title="Type in a name"
    />
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr class="header">
        <th>#</th>
        <th style="width: 60%">Name</th>
        <th style="width: 40%">Country</th>
        <th style="width: 40%">Age</th>
        <th style="width: 40%">Email</th>
        <th style="width: 40%">Surname</th>
        <th style="width: 40%">Middlename</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>germanchapperd@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Alfie</td>
        <td>Papa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
        <td>Sweden</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>chupapi@gmail.com</td>
        <td>shy</td>
        <td>Mama</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>islanda@gmail.com</td>
        <td>xerxe</td>
        <td>cici</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>funnymantio@gmail.com</td>
        <td>naknak</td>
        <td>fiif</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>natagpun@gmail.com</td>
        <td>neknek</td>
        <td>pekpek</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>ricobuenva@gmail.com</td>
        <td>hikhik</td>
        <td>hokhok</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>North/South</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>labis@gmail.com</td>
        <td>tektek</td>
        <td>kita</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Paris specialites</td>
        <td>France</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>ohhhhhh@gmail.com</td>
        <td>tektek</td>
        <td>leklek</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>funnymantio@gmail.com</td>
        <td>naknak</td>
        <td>fiif</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>natagpun@gmail.com</td>
        <td>neknek</td>
        <td>pekpek</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>ricobuenva@gmail.com</td>
        <td>hikhik</td>
        <td>hokhok</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>North/South</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>labis@gmail.com</td>
        <td>tektek</td>
        <td>kita</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Paris specialites</td>
        <td>France</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>ohhhhhh@gmail.com</td>
        <td>tektek</td>
        <td>leklek</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>funnymantio@gmail.com</td>
        <td>naknak</td>
        <td>fiif</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>natagpun@gmail.com</td>
        <td>neknek</td>
        <td>pekpek</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>ricobuenva@gmail.com</td>
        <td>hikhik</td>
        <td>hokhok</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>North/South</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>labis@gmail.com</td>
        <td>tektek</td>
        <td>kita</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Paris specialites</td>
        <td>France</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>ohhhhhh@gmail.com</td>
        <td>tektek</td>
        <td>leklek</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>funnymantio@gmail.com</td>
        <td>naknak</td>
        <td>fiif</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>natagpun@gmail.com</td>
        <td>neknek</td>
        <td>pekpek</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>ricobuenva@gmail.com</td>
        <td>hikhik</td>
        <td>hokhok</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>North/South</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>labis@gmail.com</td>
        <td>tektek</td>
        <td>kita</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Paris specialites</td>
        <td>France</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>ohhhhhh@gmail.com</td>
        <td>tektek</td>
        <td>leklek</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="pagination"></div>



